# QUnit blowing up when function with assertions bound to a child object in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, qunit

I'm trying to build a way to do PHPUnit-style test case classes in CoffeeScript.  I got very close to achieving my goal with these two classes:

QUnitTestCase.coffee:

```
class QUnitTestCase

    constructor: (name) ->
        module name
        @setUp()
        @runAllTests()

    setUp: ->
        return null

    runAllTests: ->
        for funcName, func of @
            if funcName.substr(0, 4) is 'test' and typeof func is 'function'
                testName = funcName.substr(4).charAt(0).toLowerCase() + funcName.substr(5)
                @setUp()
                test testName, func()
        return null
```

CircleTest.coffee:

```
class CircleTest extends QUnitTestCase

    constructor: ->
        super "Circle"

    setUp: ->
        @mockCanvas = mock(Canvas)
        @testObj = new Circle(@mockCanvas)
        $('canvas').css display: 'none'

    testDrawReturnsNull: =>
        returned = @testObj.draw()
        strictEqual null, returned, 'returns null'
```

However, QUnit blows up with this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertions' of undefined (qunit.js line 666)".

Looking at QUnit, I believe somehow the Test object inside QUnit becomes mis-scoped when the function that defines the assertions is bound to the object.  If I move the call to "test()" out to the child class, like this...

```
    testDrawReturnsNull: =>
        test "drawReturnsNull", =>
            returned = @testObj.draw()
            strictEqual null, returned, 'returns null'
```

... then QUnit runs fine without any errors, but this creates a kind of duplication that I don't really feel comfortable with.  Perhaps someone who understands QUnit better can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
test testName, func()
```

instead of

```
test testName, func
```

That would seem to be a problem. You want to pass the function to `test` rather than running it first and passing the returned value.